# Rails: How to use before_save to change a field value based on another field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to set a boolean field to false based on the value of another boolean field.  I tried the following with an ActiveRecord model:

```
  before_save :reconcile_xvent

  def reconcile_xvent
    self.xvent_hood = false if !self.xvent_plenum?
  end
```

But this doesn't work.  Now, many of my unit tests fail with:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
```

How can I set xvent_hood to be false if xvent_plenum is false?

**Update**

Here's what works (some of which comes from the comments/answers below):

```
before_validation :reconcile_xvent

def reconcile_xvent
  if self.xvent_hood?
    self.xvent_hood = false unless xvent_plenum?
  end
end
```

I couldn't figure out to make it work without the "if self.xvent_hood?" part....

Comment: If `xvent_hood` needs to be equal `xvent_plenum`, maybe you should just do a `xvent_hood = xvent_plenum`.

Comment: But they won't always be equal.  xvent_plenum should be able to be true, and xvent_hood false.

Comment: Try using `unless` then. `self.xvend_hood = false unless self.xvent_plenum`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`before_save` is **only** called after validation has passed. What you need to do is move `reconcile_xvent` up to `before_validation` rather than `before_save`

If you keep that method in `before_save` what will happen is that it thinks that `xvent_hood` is null, if you have a validation that checks for nullity of `xvent_hood` it will fail before the `before_save` gets called. Which probably explains why you got `RecordNotSaved` error.

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you have a boolean property, you also can't use `validate_presence_of`. See http://alexanderwong.me/post/16084280769/rails-validate-presence-of-boolean-and-arrays-mongoid

Comment: This seems to work, but why does before_save think xvent_hood is null?

Comment: it's not that before_save thinks xvent_hood is null, I believe what happend is that it failed to pass validation before before_save is even called in the first place. (Assuming if you have the proper validations in place that is, which is the reason why your records are not saving)

Comment: would be cool to see a link to the before_save documentation here.

Answer (score 18):

I just hit this issue also, the problem with the first block of code is that you're assigning the `xvent_hood` value to false which is then returned by your before_save method.

as per

> **Canceling callbacks**
>
> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the
>   associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false,
>   all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in
>   the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as
>   methods on the model, which are called last.

from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: This is the correct answer BUT how do you resolve the issue?  How do you assign a boolean to false in a before_save callback?

Comment: To assign a boolean to false in your before_save ensure you explicitly return true at the end of your callback.

For example:
`def before_save(record)
    my_false_bool = false
    return true
end`

Comment: That is the first time i've seen ruby behave in an obnoxious manner due to it omitting regular keywords like return. OMFG that is frusterating.