# Simple calculation not working before save, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a `base_price` field, a `shipping_price` field, and a `total_price` field.

It's a simple `base_price` plus `shipping_price` equals `total_price`. For some reason, I cannot get this simple calculation to work when saving my model.

Here's my code:

**item.rb**

```
before_save :total_price_calculator

private

  def total_price_calculator
    self.total_price.to_i = self.base_price.to_i + self.shipping_price.to_i
  end
```

It's failing to make the calculation and save it in the database and I'm not really getting an error as to why.

Comment: it works fine for me with your code minus all the `to_i` methods. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to the following

`self.total_price` it automatically saves integer when assigned to this any value integer, that's why you don't need to call `to_i`

After modified

```
before_save :total_price_calculator

private

def total_price_calculator
    self.total_price = base_price.to_i + shipping_price.to_i
end
```

You don't need to use `self` on `base_price` and `shipping_price` because that is are already have values which given from form.

Or you can use directly looks like below

```
before_save {self.total_price = self.base_price.to_i + self.shipping_price.to_i}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a method on an assignment here and I suspect that this *might be the issue*, try it like this:

```
def total_price_calculator
  self.total_price = self.base_price + self.shipping_price
end
```

`total_price` is going to be an `int` anyway

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's still not saving `total_price`.

Comment: What class do you use for the defined fields `base_price` and `shipping_price` ?

Comment: All three of them are integers.

Comment: then to begin with you do not need the `to_i` conversions as they already are integers. Are you using a form to pass those values?

Comment: Can you verify that the values passed to those attributes are integers so that they have values and are not nil when the assignment happens? Also what is the value of `total_price` after save

Answer (score 0):

Try using another methods like before_update/create/validate, inserting breakpoint too see what happens there, returning false to cancel all following callbacks.

Perhaps this is relatable:
[Rails: How to use before_save to change a field value based on another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782969/rails-how-to-use-before-save-to-change-a-field-value-based-on-another-field)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def total_price_calculator
  self.total_price.to_i = self.base_price.to_i + self.shipping_price.to_i
  true
end
```

sometimes if it comes out as nil, that returns false for your validation which will rollback the record and not save.

Or to further debug try...

```
def total_price_calculator
  puts self.base_price.to_i
  puts self.shipping_price.to_i
  puts self.base_price.to_i + self.shipping_price.to_i
  puts self.total_price.to_i = self.base_price.to_i + self.shipping_price.to_i
  self.total_price.to_i = self.base_price.to_i + self.shipping_price.to_i
  true
end
```

if the last puts returns false or nil, your save will fail validation and not save.